# generated gradle project inside of maven project

Tags: maven, gradle, node-modules, jhipster, spotbugs

I generated a maven application with jhipster.
Now I want to add the spotbugs-check to my pipeline.
The plugin says that there are two projects detected - one maven-project (the one I'm working on) and one gradle-project at /node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/server/templates. I have no Idea where this gradle-project comes from and how I should handle it.
The pipeline fails because this project can't be build... Can anyone tell me how to delete this project or how to make it build/ignore?[enter image description here][1]

I tried to exclude the directory from spotbugs buildpath, but it didn't work

My .gitlab-ci.yml looks like this:

```
variables:
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version"
  SECURE_LOG_LEVEL: "debug"
stages:
- sast

sast:
  stage: sast
include:
- template: Security/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml
```

Comment: The gradle project comes from node_modules where JHipster installs itself. You must configure spotbugs to exclude node_modules directory from scanning, read their docs, as a bonus it'll run faster. Your question mentions a pipeline and a plugin but without enough details to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I added my gitlab-ci file to the question, do you know how to exclude the node_modules directory from scanning? I already tried with the 
`artifacts:
         exclude:`
but it didn't work

Comment: Your gitlab pipeline does not make any reference to spotbugs so this is not how you configured it, did you configure it in pom.xml? Please edit your question with relevant details. Also why using spotbugs when IDEs do similar job?